# Android端末をキーボードとして使うようなアプリの仕組み

Tags: android, usb

Android端末をPCにUSB接続してタッチスクリーンをフリックしてPCに入力するようなアプリを作る場合、どうすればいいのでしょうか?

AndroidはLinuxカーネル上で動いているのでLinuxのUSB gadget driverなどを使えばできるかと思ったのですが、USB Device Controllerというものがないとできないようです。

AndroidにUSB HIDのキーボードの振る舞いをエミュレーションさせる必要があるのでしょうがどうすればいいかわからないです。

上記のような機能をAndroidで実現したい場合は、どうすればよいのでしょうか?

Comment: 使いたいだけなら既にあるものを使うほうが手早いっス。 BLE 接続なら `Rickey+` とか Wi-Fi なら `RemoteMouse` とか USB なら  `USB Keyboard apk` とか。せっかくのスマホだから、使い勝手でいうなら有線よりは無線のほうが断然いい。プログラム組みたいってことならその辺から情報収集できるかもしれないです。

Comment: @774RR 作るならどういうところから始めればいいのでしょうか?
Linux USB HIDとかですかね?

Answer (score -2):

色々やり方はあると思いますが、USBで送るっていうのが限定であれば
例えば、普通にテキストとして外部ストレージに保存してから、PC側から
それを読みとるとかが考えられるように思うんです。
スレッドでループさせて読み込み読み込み、また読み込みって感じで。

すみませんそれ以外思いつかないので逆にあったら知りたいです。
リスナーで外部からタイミングよく起動するような。